# Problem detecting mic on SONY VIOS PCG 7192L

Tags: drivers, 9.10, microphone

Ubuntu 9.10 problem detecting mic on **SONY VIOS PCG 7192L**, pls help.

Answer (score 1):

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems for the steps to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at Input tab on Sound Preferences?

You can go to `System > Preferences > Sound`, select the `Input` tab, and see if it is muted or the device is selected.

You might have alread tried this.

Comment: Is not working. nothing on the input tab.